# Alternative of announceForAccessibility in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, accessibility

is there any alternative of `announceForAccessibility` in jetpack compose which will announce a text automatically for an event.

Comment: Could you please describe the context in which you're trying to make an announcement? The documentation for [announceForAccessibility](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#announceForAccessibility(java.lang.CharSequence)) explicitly says "Note: The event generated with this API carries no semantic meaning, and is appropriate only in exceptional situations." - it may be that JC has covered the situation you are talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem with live region is that it will only announce if the Text is visible on the screen, otherwise it will be ignored. An alternative would be to retrieve the view and use the announceForAccessibility itself.

```
val localView = LocalView.current
localView.announceForAccessibility("your text to be announced")
```